# What does the vector length of a rgb color in vector space mean

Tags: color-space, color-conversion

I'm working with raw camera data where the color values are in full float. In RGB space represented as 3D cartesian coordinate, every color can be plotted as a vector in the positive x,y,z coordinates. What does the magnitude, or the length of the vector represent? Originally I interpreted as intensity or luminance of the color value. But I'm getting confused over another concept, which is the sum of all 3 colors component. So what does the sum of all 3 color components represent and what does the vector length of the RGB vector represent?

Comment: Hello, This looks to be a domain specific question rather than a programmatic one. So you may want to post it on https://photo.stackexchange.com/. That said, as per my understanding, the length of the vector along with the orientation (angle of the vector w.r.t x,y,z axes) is simply another way of representing the color in addition to the co-ordinate system. This arises from the observation that there can be different combinations that result in the same value when summed (Eg:  50,100,150; 100,50,150, 150,0,150)....

Comment: raw data format depends on camera. Often the values are related to intensity, but they are not normalized between channels (this is just not done, just not to lose information). You need to profile the sensor to get the response of the sensor. Usually you have linear (or nearly linear) intensities (unlike most RGB you see on web, which are gamma corrected). Note: camera sensors (but on few large and very professional video camera) have one value (a single channel/colour) per pixel. Demosaicing is needed to get RGB (and possibly with advanced algorithms)

Comment: Sum and length of RGB do not represent any useful concept, so there is no concept for them. In fact the definition of most RGB colour spaces (as sRGB) are pretty arbitrary. AdobeRGB was defined because a typo when copying from a sRGB draft.